# iOS Safari's iframe doesn't get device orientation and motion events

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, mobile-safari, device-orientation

I was trying to learn about HTML5 device orientation API. I found few demos that worked great on Android and iOS when I opened them on browser.

Demo: https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html

Now, when I included those pages in an iframe and opened in Android (chrome), it worked as expected. But, in iOS safari, the page just didn't do anything. Looks like the `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` is true, but no `deviceorientation` event is triggered inside the iframe.

Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/sumevugiga/1

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Add an event listener on orientationchange

```
document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
  isLandScape = Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90;
  // handle_orientation_change
});
```

Comment: The entire problem is that this doesn't work in an iFrame.